# Async, Await, Promise in angular controller gives cannot read property "then" of undefined.

Tags: angularjs, promise

The problem here is that if I run this as a normal function, then `loadAllUsers()` (a http call to a nodejs controller) not be finished and there will be no data. Which of cause gives error in `self.tenants.filter`

```
function findTenants ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    var self = this;
    try { 
        self.searchText    = "aa"
        self.tenants       = loadAllUsers();
        self.querySearch   = querySearch;
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }

    function querySearch (query) {
        return query ? self.tenants.filter( createFilterFor(query) ) : self.tenants;
    }

    function createFilterFor(query) {
        var lowercaseQuery = angular.lowercase(query);
        return function filterFn(tenants) {
            return (tenants.value.indexOf(lowercaseQuery) === 0);
        };
    }
}
```

Since `loadAllUsers()` is already a promise, I might as well make `findTenants` an async function so I can wait for the result.

```
async function findTenants ($scope, $mdDialog) {
    var self = this;
    try { 
        self.searchText    = "aa"
        self.tenants       = await loadAllUsers();
        self.querySearch   = querySearch;
    }
    etc....
```

Now it waits for the data, and the data actually arrives and is put into `self.tenants` which is great... but then I get this:

[image]

You would think this error is from the `loadAllUsers()` promise, but its not. Cause even if I comment out `loadAllUsers()` I still get the error.  So it is probably `mdDialog` or Angular Material which im using here which throws the error.

As soon as I change `function findTenants` to `async function findTenants` then I get the error.

Any suggestions?  Is there another way to wait for `loadAllUsers()` ?

Comment: What is the expected type for `this.tenants`? Based on your description, in the original code it was a promise but in your modified code it is now the actual data. Did you update the template code that makes use of `tenants`? Maybe there is an async call that expects a promise by the template code but now its the actual data and not a promise (ie. you did not modify the consuming code).

Comment: this.tenants is just an array of json data from the nodejs controller. If I just feed it directly like `this.tenants = [{aaa:bbb},{aaa:bbb}]` then everything works perfectly.  And no I didnt modify angular material, its way above my skill level hehe :-)

Comment: Got it!! -  your question gave me an idea, so I moved the async await to where the problem was, in the query search function where it does the filter. So I did this... `async function querySearch (query) {
            self.tenants = await loadAllUsers();` rest of function the same. And now everything works :)